# javascript alert code in servlet is not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, servlets

Hi i have written a code that after insert data into database based on the result i want to show the alert,but its not working in google chrome,it is printing my code as it is.here is the my code,can anyone check this and help me out..

```
 int addResult =   dao.addUser(str1,str3,str4);
         if(addResult > 0){
             out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
             out.println("alert('Inserted SuccessFully');");
             out.println("location = 'home.jsp';");
             out.println("</script>");
         }
         else{
             out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
             out.println("alert('Some Error has occured,please try again later');");
             out.println("location = 'home.jsp';");
             out.println("</script>"); 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Result should be appended to the  tag. 
You can try in the following way.

```
     var head  = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = srcPath;
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
    head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: how can i include this code  in servlet,this is pure js code right,